# Изменение дизайна ucoz

Tags: ucoz

Потребовалось сделать сайт на укозе.
Там, при редактировании шаблонов, есть список "кодов", которые везде будут что-то вставлять вместо себя (то есть шаблонизатор).
К примеру:

```
$GROUP_ID$ - ID группы пользователя
$HOME_PAGE_LINK$ - адрес главной страницы сайта ("Общие настройки")
$IP_ADDRESS$ - IP адрес
```

Так вот, раз там нельзя работать со скриптами, то понятно, что ничего поменять в работе, к примеру, `$IP_ADDRESS$` я не могу.
Но, для формы регистрации есть куча своих кодов, типа `$EMAIL_FL$`.
**Вопрос**: можно ли как-то поменять то, что ставится заместо этих кодов, то есть их шаблоны?
**Вопрос-2**: можно ли как-то убрать некоторые (необязательные) поля с формы регистрации, типа аватара? Я из шаблона формы регистрации удаляю их, это сохраняется, но на самой странице поля не исчезают.
**Вопрос-3**: можно ли как-то изменить дизайн меню? Конкретно, я хочу прикрутить к нему JS красивый.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Нет, изменять коды шаблонов нельзя.
2. Можно, смотрите настройки модуля «Пользователи».
3. Да, смотрите глобальные блоки, либо попробуйте изменить меню с помощью конструктора дизайна.